# Join tables having three column if and only if id exists

Tags: mysql

In my table calendar, I have three columns (sal, esal, pt) and either column having id that points another table. I want to join sal, esal and pt if and only if id exists.
Ex:

```
calendar table
--------------
id  sal     esal    pt
1   0       10      0     
2   0       0       11
3   12      0       0
4   0       13      0
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood. You have other tables like `sals` that has a field `id` and the field `sal` in `calendar` is a foreign key to `sals.id`?

Comment: What have you tried?  What isn't working?  What do you mean by "only if id exists"?  All of these records have `id` values.  Do you mean those `0` values in the other columns?  If those are foreign keys, they shouldn't *allow* values which don't exist in the related table.  Why *do* they?

Comment: Not sure what your question is. And not sure what your example is: Is that what your table looks like? Or is it what your expected output looks like? What have you tried so far? Please edit your question accordingly, as currently it's unclear what you're asking, and also it's a "please write this code for me" question, which will likely lead to this question being closed if left as-is.

Answer (score 0):

You can add conditions in your join statement. Like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM calendar a
LEFT JOIN table_sal b ON a.sal = b.id AND a.sal > 0
LEFT JOIN table_esal c ON a.esal = c.id AND a.esal > 0
LEFT JOIN table_pt d ON a.pt = d.id AND a.pt > 0
```

Joins will not be done if IDs are not greater than 0